# Calling a table function using HQL to Oracle or SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, hibernate

In my java application I was writing TSQL queries to only query the SQL server.
Later, the requirement of the project changed and I needed to be able to query an Oracle database aswell. In order to do so, I have re-written the TSQL queries in HQL.

In this case, HQL should run on both the Sql Server DB and Oracle DB.

While migrating the TSQL queries I faced a problem. In order to call a function which returns a table in PL/SQL you need to wrap the function in a table function.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(MyFunction(1))
```

On the other hand, in TSQL you can just call the function in the query

```
SELECT * FROM MyFunction(1)
```

How can I handle the function call in HQL ? Or is there way to call the function in standard SQL so it can run on both databases ?

Comment: I've had to deal with that kind of problems in the past. I wrote my own `Dialect` class extend. But now I use QueryDSL which tend to make everything just simplier.